Man finds out his lover is really a man?
I believe I remember secretly watching parts if not an entire movie with my parents when I was a child, unknown to them. Unless I dreamed about this and it didn't really happen. In the movie there's a man and a woman. The woman may have been a performer and may have resembled Sade. They have an intimate moment where this man finds out the woman was really, or used to be, a man. I believe it was a loving film. Nit that it matters but,I believe it was an American film. But it could have been a foreign film. I just want to know if my mind is that creative and I came up with everything in my head or that I'm not crazy. I'd love to see this movie again in my life!!!!!

Any idea how long ago you watched this? When it came out?

Any possibility it was The Crying Game?  That's the most famous "trans-gender" film I know of.

@Johnny Bones - It sounds very much like The Crying Game. I think you should post that as an answer.

It could be M Butterfly, but the revelation was so shocking I doubt you would not be able to remember it. But a good movie nonetheless.

Someone snarfed my answer.  :o)

Reminded me of Ace ventura pet detective. But its funny one.

@AnkitSharma Ace Ventura paid homage to Crying Game, in fact they used the same song while Carey was crying in the shower.

@BenPlont ohhh....didn't know that previously

Sounds like The Crying Game.

An unlikely kind of friendship develops between Fergus, an Irish Republican Army volunteer, and Jody, a kidnapped British soldier lured into an IRA trap by Jude, another IRA member. When the hostage-taking ends up going horribly wrong, Fergus escapes and heads to London, where he seeks out Jody's lover, a hairdresser named Dil. Fergus adopts the name "Jimmy" and gets a job as a day laborer. He also starts seeing Dil, who knows nothing about Fergus' IRA background. But there are some things about Dil that Fergus doesn't know, either...

